# MATLAB array of libpointer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, matlab

I'm currently developing a wrapper for a C++ library so it can be used in MATLAB. I want my C++ objects to be in MATLAB so the user can do something with them. Actually I'm casting those C++ objects to `void *` because MATLAB only supports C headers. These C functions look like this:

`__declspec(dllexport) void *getPtr (int someArgument);`

In MATLAB I'm calling the functions like this:

`ptr = calllib('LibName', 'getPtr', 42);`

In MATLAB the ptr is now a `<1x1 lib.pointer>`. I can't do anything with it besides to pass it to another C function, like the following:

`__declspec(dllexport) int doSomethingWithPtr (void *ptr);`

So I'm calling `result = calllib('LibName', 'doSomethingWithPtr', ptr);` within MATLAB which works perfectly fine and executes this function with the pointer as argument. (I've debugged the C code and the pointer is the same as the one returned from `getPtr`.

My C function needs more than one pointer to work like intended by the C++ library. I already passed numeric data within MATLAB matrices to C which works perfectly with the C type `mxArray` (see: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/apiref/mxarray.html). For the purpose of handing over multiple pointers to C I constructed an array of MATLAB `lib.pointer`s like this:

```
A = [];

for i = 1:10
    ptr = calllib('LibName', 'getPtr', i);
    A = [A, ptr];    
end
```

And I'm calling another C function (`__declspec(dllexport) int doSomethingWithPtrArray (mxArray *ptrarr);`) within MATLAB:

```
ptr = calllib('LibName', 'doSomethingWithPtrArray', A);
```

Within the C function I'm getting the correct array dimensions with `mxGetN(ptrarr)` and `mxGetM(ptrarr)`. I also can retrieve the data pointer with:

`void *mexPtr = mxGetData(ptrarr);`

The problem is that `mexPtr` and the following pointers point to locations in the memory I didn't even allocate or know before. Perhaps MATLAB does some intelligent wrapping when calling the function with `void *` and doesn't do that, when I'm passing over the array. (I think I'm getting the addresses to the MATLAB `lib.pointer` wrapper object??)

Does anybody have a clue (or a workaround) how I get the correct pointers out of the mxArray, so I can evaluate multiple pointers at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found no 'beautiful' solution, I constructed a helper method in C++, which lets me build a vector of my own:

```
void *buildClassifierVectorBase(void *vector, void *classifier)
{
    typedef IClassifierManager<input_dtype, feature_dtype, annotation_dtype> class_man_t;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<class_man_t>> *classMgrs;

    if (vector == nullptr)
    {
        classMgrs = new std::vector<std::shared_ptr<class_man_t>>();            
    } 
    else
    {
        classMgrs = static_cast<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<class_man_t>> *>(vector);
    }

    class_man_t *cls = static_cast<class_man_t *>(classifier);
    classMgrs->push_back(std::shared_ptr<class_man_t>(cls));        

    return static_cast<void *>(classMgrs);  
}
```

This method I can use within MATLAB to build that vector of pointers like this:

```
ptr1 = calllib('LibName', 'getPtr', 42);
ptr2 = calllib('LibName', 'getPtr', 43);
ptr3 = calllib('LibName', 'getPtr', 44);

vector = calllib('LibName', 'buildClassifierVectorBase', libpointer, ptr1);
vector = calllib('LibName', 'buildClassifierVectorBase', vector, ptr2);
vector = calllib('LibName', 'buildClassifierVectorBase', vector, ptr3);
```

Now I can call my method `doSomethingWithPtrArray`:

```
ptr = calllib('LibName', 'doSomethingWithPtrArray', vector);
```

This solution works, but is not the prettiest...